# Xubuntu Live used to copy files - I/O error - where's the log?

Tags: xubuntu, thunar

I regularly use Xubuntu 18.10 on a live pendrive for when I need to transfer data from one NTFS HD to another when Windows is corrupt, for example.  I'm experiencing (I suspect) bad sectors on one HDD and Thunar is showing I/O Errors.

Does Thunar record these errors in a log file and what is the log file's location?  Will it save to a live pendrive?

Otherwise, to record the errors reported by Thunar, I'm screen-shotting each error and saving to a jpeg - there's got to be a better way?

I'm not adverse to using Kubuntu or other, if that's a workable solution.

Comment: When using a 'live' system, you are using a fs (file-system) created on boot and located in memory; so even if stored in a log file (it'd be in the fallback `dmesg` or sysd log I'd assume) I'd not bother recording it, just have your system check for errors using `badblocks` - so it's not just by chance (because you tried to use that sector), but the whole device [disk] can be scanned.  Anything saved in the 'live' system is lost on shutdown/reboot (unless persistence is enabled, or you `scp` etc. the file elsewhere)

Comment: Unless you have enabled persistence, the log file won't save to the pen drive. A simple google search would have revealed the log location, though.